# How to cast or convert string data type to integer in order to run sum function in linq usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, object, entity, type-conversion

```
 var logs = (from m in db.AccountFileOperationLogList
     where m.OperationId == OperationId
     where m.JobStatus == "OK"
     select m.JobFileSize).Sum();
```

`m.JobFileSize` is `nvarchar` database column without any `null` or `string` values.

Comment: Anything you tried yourself?

Comment: Sure, please try with yourself too :)

Comment: Well, take it or leave it. Why? Because you help yourself. People are much more willing to answer if they see that you've tried yourself first. And because your own efforts clarify more than you might think. For instance, it would probably have shown that you use Entity Framework, an important detail you failed to provide.

Comment: There is no LINQ to Entities/SQL solution. You should ask yourself why are you storing numeric data in `nvarchar` column.

Comment: Guys, I can convert it from the database side without any problem. The point is why we are not able to convert it without any problem in linq as we can handle it in sql easily

Comment: That was a question topic. I didn't store any numeric data in nvarchar column. Let's please focus the problem instead of attack or defence answers. @IvanStoev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 var logs = (from m in db.AccountFileOperationLogList
 where m.OperationId == OperationId
 where m.JobStatus == "OK"
 select m.JobFileSize).ToList();// getting data from db to local memory

 logs.Sum(s => int.Parse(s));//and then you can use `int.Parse(s)` function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var logs = (from m in db.AccountFileOperationLogList
 where m.OperationId == OperationId
 where m.JobStatus == "OK"
 select m.JobFileSize).Sum(s => int.Parse(s));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Raised same conversion error. s variable is pointless :
{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: you may want to tag your question with linq-to-entities